# Rails 5, Devise: How to handle remote: true JS requests when logged out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app running Rails 5.1.5 and Devise 4.4.3.

Many links in my application have `remote: true`, which submit a :js format request to the controller, which has `authenticate_user!` set as a before_action.

The controller redirects the JS request to `user_sessions#new` (Devise), which seems to have no idea what to do with it.

How can one modify a standard Devise installation to deal with an unauthenticated JS request that gets caught by `authenticate_user!`?

Comment: Good question. I think I have similar links but usually the original view where the links are shown are views that needs authentication. So not really a problem. The auth callback is more a safeguard than a real feature to me in this case, so resulting ill design behavior is only a result of ill user usage. But I am curious to see what other coders have done for this issue.

Comment: @Maxence I use these links for navigation purposes as they speed up the app somewhat (fewer items have to load). I can't have the app vulnerable to unauthenticated access on certain pages. Unless I'm going about it the wrong way, I'm surprised Devise wouldn't sort out something that seems so elementary.

Comment: Well I mean if those links are to be only accessible by authed users, why show it to non authed users ? You can discriminate in your view with devise helpers : `current_user` `user_signed_in` ..

Comment: @Maxence An example is if a user keeps the webpage open but the server signs them out due to inactivity.

Comment: Then maybe you can remove the authing callback for the very view (or views) that your links are pointing to and explicitly redirect to the sign in view in case user is not logged in, before the `respond_to` method. So that you force the sign in manually. You can probably achieve that if the devise authing callback helper cannot perform it.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your `remote: true` based on user signed in or not

```rb
<%= link_to post_likes_path(post), method: :post, remote: user_signed_in? %>
```

Basically you will show one version on the link (with `remote :true`) when the user is signed in and show the regular plain link when the user is not.

Comment: While loading the dom user_signed_in? will be always true. may be user has logged out in other tab,So this will also submit always true.